# _tkinter.TclError: can't use "pyimage1" as iconphoto: not a photo image

Tags: python, tkinter

When I tried to add the file dialog button, I kept getting a error like this:

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't use "pyimage1" as iconphoto: not a photo image
```

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog
from file_dialog import filedialog

root = Tk()
img = PhotoImage(file='icon.png')

root.geometry("700x500") # the application window size
root.iconphoto(False,img) #application icon
root.title("I need a NAME!") # title of window

def file_dialog():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="Downloads", title="Select A File To Start", filetypes=(("mp4 files", "*.mp4"),("mov files", "*.mov"),("png files", "*.png"),("jpeg files", "*.jpeg"),("jpg files", "*.jpg")))


def file_dialog_button(app):
    app = app.tk()
    button = app.Button(app, text="Start!", command=file_dialog)
    button.pack(app)

root.mainloop()

print("Succesful Build")

file_dialog()
file_dialog_button()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: This makes no sense, `from file_dialog import filedialog`?? You have already imported `filedialog` from `tkinter`

Comment: @acw1668 When I ran the code it threw a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file_dialog'`

Comment: @Derek I removed not relevant code and just focus on `iconphoto()`.

Comment: Sorry @acw1668 I'm not a critic, I'm agreeing with you

Comment: Your code seems to be trying to load image as `root.iconphoto`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few modifications to your code that enables you to load images into the root window icon.

`from tkinter import *` is a bad practice so I've changed it to `import tkinter as tk` and made the necessary changes.

The problem was that you were attempting to reference functions and variables before they were declared.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x500") # the application window size
root.title("I need a NAME!") # title of window

def file_dialog():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="Downloads",
        title="Select A File To Start",
        filetypes=(
            ("mp4 files", "*.mp4"),
            ("mov files", "*.mov"),
            ("png files", "*.png"),
            ("jpeg files", "*.jpeg"),
            ("jpg files", "*.jpg")))

    if filename:
        root.img = tk.PhotoImage(file=filename)
        root.iconphoto( False, root.img ) # application icon

app = tk.Toplevel(root)
app.transient( root )
button = tk.Button(app, text="Start!", command=file_dialog)
button.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)

root.mainloop()

print("Successful Build")
```

Comment: at least you changed the import for `tkinter`, but why import from `PIL` if you don't use it? also what is that print statement? it will show only when you close the window, which means it will be more like a `successful build destruction`, otherwise great answer

Answer (score 0):

1. According to your error the problem is with your file format, change your tkinter window icon format to `.ico`. An icon can only be in `.ico` format.
2. Remove this `from file_dialog import filedialog` import, you have already imported filedialog from tkinter.
3. Change your app window to `TopLevel()` window. You can learn more about them [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_toplevel.htm)
4. In your call for `file_dialog_button()` you haven't passed a value for the variable `app`.

Your final code should look like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
img = PhotoImage(file='icon.ico')

root.geometry("700x500") # the application window size
root.iconphoto(False,img) #application icon
root.title("I need a NAME!") # title of window

def file_dialog():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="Downloads", title="Select A File To Start", filetypes=(("mp4 files", "*.mp4"),("mov files", "*.mov"),("png files", "*.png"),("jpeg files", "*.jpeg"),("jpg files", "*.jpg")))


def file_dialog_button(app):
    app = Toplevel()
    button = Button(app, text="Start!", command=file_dialog)
    button.pack(app)

print("Succesful Build")

file_dialog()
file_dialog_button('exmaple_name')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: one slight addition: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: which basically means their first line should look like `from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button`. also you either use `PIL` which means this `ImageTk.PhotoImage` and `Image.open()` or you remove that import and add `PhotoImage` to first import line: `from tkinter import Tk, Toplevel, Button, PhotoImage`